# Simplify Multiple Constructor

Tags: java

I would like to know if how can I simplify this 2 constructor:

```
public class MyClass{
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private String d;


    public MyClass(String a, String B, String c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }

     public MyClass(String a, String B, String c, String d) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
        this.d = d; 
    }
}
```

Should I used super or this?

Comment: "Should I used super or this?" Try both. See which is even possible.

Comment: @AndyTurner how?

Comment: Write `super(/* something */);` and try to compile it. See what the compiler says. Same for `this(/* something */);`.

Answer (score 0):

If you call to super() inside a constructor, you're calling the constructor of the parent class (Object in this case), but it does not make sense in this context.

An approach to reduce the repetition could be:

```
public MyClass(String a, String b, String c) {
    this(a, b, c, null); 
    // or 
    // this(a, b, c, "");
}
```

We can chain constructor calls and reduce repeated assignments.

You can then call:

```
MyClass a = new MyClass("A", "B", "C");
MyClass b = new MyClass("A", "B", "C", "D");
```